# Newman Docker error: unknown option `--url'

Tags: docker, collections, postman, newman

I found the option was created to run newman with docker image and postman collection on MAC by running the following

```
docker pull postman/newman_ubuntu1404

docker run -t postman/newman_ubuntu1404 --url="https://www.getpostman.com/collections/8a0c9bc08f062d12dcda"
```

When running newman on the image with the postman collection the following error is returned.

```
error: unknown option `--url'
```

Docker version is Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

Is this supported?

Comment: In docker we don't have any parameter like --url. Run docker run --help for the available options. Furthermore you can directly run that image by using "docker run -d --name 'mynewman' postman/newman_ubuntu1404". What the url parameter supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found this [github issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/1532) where it says to replace `--url=` with `run`:

```
docker run -t postman/newman_ubuntu1404 run "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/8a0c9bc08f062d12dcda"
```

It seems to work...

```
docker run -t postman/newman_ubuntu1404 run "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/8a0c9bc08f062d12dcda"
newman: Newman v4 deprecates support for the v1 collection format
  Use the Postman Native app to export collections in the v2 format

newman

newmanTest

→ GET with URL Params
  GET http://httpbin.org/get?lol=true [200 OK, 542B, 339ms]
  ✓  Response contains params

→ POST with JSON body
  POST http://httpbin.org/post [200 OK, 704B, 158ms]
  ✓  Check POST param in response

→ DELETE request
  DELETE http://httpbin.org/delete [200 OK, 606B, 184ms]
  ✓  Status code is 200

→ PUT with form data
  PUT http://httpbin.org/put [200 OK, 687B, 159ms]
  ✓  Test form data

┌─────────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│                         │ executed │   failed │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│              iterations │        1 │        0 │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│                requests │        4 │        0 │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│            test-scripts │        4 │        0 │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│      prerequest-scripts │        0 │        0 │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│              assertions │        4 │        0 │
├─────────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────┤
│ total run duration: 1204ms                    │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ total data received: 1.52KB (approx)          │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ average response time: 210ms                  │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: The url flag was taken from Postman docs below but this looks like it works, thanks.

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/newman_with_docker

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it as an answer if you think it provides a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, will do. While it solved the problem and the collection ran, one question, is if the collection also requires environment variables as input, how is this added in the same command? When running with newman for example from the cmd line, it is added as an option with -e Dev-Test-1-Env.postman_environment.json

Comment: Can you check if these [examples](https://hub.docker.com/r/postman/newman_ubuntu1404/) actually work? I think they cover your case.

Answer (score 1):

The docker image used in the question is now obsolete and [the new official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/postman/newman/) comes along a working example that does not use "--url"

docker pull postman/newman

docker run -t postman/newman run "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/8a0c9bc08f062d12dcda"